# Android: fix RecyclerView filtering on spinner selection?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-spinner

I have a RecyclerView list of a number of CardViews.  I would like to filter the list when the user selects an item from a spinner dropdown dialog.  The item selection from the spinner narrows down the list to a smaller set of the original CardViews. My problem is that the list is being filtered somehow when I add a new CardView to the list which occurs before the user ever makes any item selection with the spinner.  So no new CardView shows in the Recyclerview list, it is just a blank RecyclerView list.  I only want the CardViews to be filtered when the user makes an item selection from the spinner, not every time a CardView is added to the RecyclerView list.  What am I missing here?

```
MainActivity
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView sRecyclerView;    
    private MyRecylerAdapter adapter;
    private List<ListItem> allList;
    ...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // For filtering by the CardView type.
    final Spinner spinner2;        
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.skycard_filter);
    String[] spinnerItems2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.skycard_filters);        
    final CustomAdapter<String> adapter2 = new CustomAdapter<>
            (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerItems2);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    spinner2.setPrompt("Filter CardView type");

    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
            int position, long id) {

            String type = spinnerItems2[position];
            final ArrayList<ListItem> filteredModelList2 = adapter.filter2(adapter.listItems,type);
            adapter.setFilter(filteredModelList2);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected (AdapterView < ? > adapterView){
            // auto-generated
        }
    });
}

Adapter
public class MyRecylerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public List<ListItem> listItems;
    ...
    // Do Search filtering from MainActivity.
    public ArrayList<ListItem> filter2(List<ListItem> models, String filterType) {

        final ArrayList<ListItem> filteredModelList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ListItem model:models) {
            final String cardTypeTest = model.getType();

            if (cardTypeTest.equals(filterType)) {
                filteredModelList2.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList2;
    }

    public void setFilter2(ArrayList<ListItem> listItem) {
        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        listItems.addAll(listItem);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are always filtering with the word "Type", you should filter based on the word which you selected from the spinner.

You can one more param `filterType` in `filter2`

```
public ArrayList<ListItem> filter2(List<ListItem> models, String filterType) {

        final ArrayList<ListItem> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ListItem model:models) {
            final String cardTypeTest = model.getType();

            if (cardTypeTest.equalsIgnoreCase(filterType)) {
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }
```

And while calling you can call like this,

```
        final String[] spinnerItems2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.skycard_filters);

        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {

                String type = spinnerItems2[position];

                final ArrayList<ListItem> filteredModelList2 = adapter.filter2(adapter.listItems, type);

                adapter.setFilter(filteredModelList2);
//                switch (position) {
//                    case 0:
//                        
//                        break;
//                ...
//                    case 4:
//                        break;
//                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected (AdapterView < ? > adapterView){
                // auto-generated
            }
        });
```

Comment: Ah, ok.  I will give it a try.

Comment: final ArrayList<> in MainActivity is throwing an error: "filter2 in Adapter cannot be applied to List<ListItem>.

Comment: Also, the adapter.setFilter() in MainActivity is throwing an error setFilter(ArrayList<ListItem>) in Adapter cannot be applied to ArrayList<ListItem>String.

Comment: I use Android Studio...only options to try to fix are "Create method 'filter2'" and "Remove 2nd parameter from  method 'filter2'".

Comment: Ok will do now.

Comment: Should I be updating setFilter() in the Adapter to add String parameter since "type" was added in the "adapter.setFilter()" of the MainActivity?

Comment: Ok that removes the error warning in the MainActivity but now it says "type is never used in setFilter() method.  How would I be add "type" parameter to the 3 lines within the setFilter() method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151017/discussion-between-muthukrishnan-rajendran-and-ajw).